# How to access code behind from Tablet/Phone template?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am taking over a project with a DashboardPage and a DashboardPageViewModel that are linked through DI's ViewModelLocator. The Dashboard page have the following code that separates the Xaml/Code behinds into two separate templates.

```
   private void SetContent()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Dashboardpage setContent");

            switch(Device.Idiom)
            {
                case TargetIdiom.Phone:
                    Content = new PrimaryPhoneLayout
                    {
                        RegionContent = RegionContent
                    };
                    break;
                case TargetIdiom.Tablet:
                    Content = new PrimaryTabletLayout(deviceDisplay)
                    {
                        RegionContent = RegionContent
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"{Device.Idiom} is not a supported idom");
            }
        }
```

I want to add a button in both Phone/Tablet xaml and handle the logic within DashboardPage. How can I make a reference to Dashboard page when these XAML files are linked to their individual code behind and not Dashboard Page?

To elaborate further, DashboardPage derives from MenuContainerPage that allows me to slide in/out of my slide menu. I want to handle this logic through a button that I implemented in both Tablet/Phone layout.

Comment: What it looks from the code above is that there gotta exist two classes called: `PrimaryPhoneLayout` and `PrimaryTabletLayout` which are responsible for all the UI on the `DashboardPage`. Those two classes will have the UI in code or will have a counterpart XAML file. 

Sorry that I cannot add more but the information you provided is not enough.

Comment: @pinedax Yes, that is correct. The code shown above is within DashboardPage.cs. These Layout files have their own xaml.cs files where I can handle the input of the button. However, I want to handle the logic within DashboardPage.cs since that's where I have access to the menu I want to hide. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

I would start by creating an `interface` with the events I want to expose from my `ContentView`

For the sample, I will call this interface as `IMenuOptionHandler` and it would look like this

```
public interface IMenuOptionHandler
{
    event EventHandler OnSlideIn;

    event EventHandler OnSlideOut;
}
```

Here we have two events that will be invoked from our ContentViews. You can add as many as you wish.

Then we need to make our ContentViews to implement this interface:

```
public partial class PrimaryPhoneLayouts : ContentView, IMenuOptionHandler
{
    //...

    #region "IMenuOptionHandler implementation"
    public event EventHandler OnSlideIn;

    public event EventHandler OnSlideOut;
    #endregion

    void OnSlideInButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSlideIn?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    void OnSlideOutButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSlideOut?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public partial class PrimaryTabletLayout : ContentView, IMenuOptionHandler
{
    // ...

    #region "IMenuOptionHandler implementation"
    public event EventHandler OnSlideIn;

    public event EventHandler OnSlideOut;
    #endregion

    void OnSlideInButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSlideIn?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    void OnSlideOutButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSlideOut?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

As you can see both classes are implementing our interface.

Also, I added two sets of methods which are the methods that you will hook to the Buttons on the XAML.

Let's imagine that your XAML looks like this:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Button Text="SlideIn" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                Clicked="OnSlideInButtonClicked" />
        <Button Text="SlideOut" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                Clicked="OnSlideOutButtonClicked" />           
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Both XAML should have the buttons and the `Clicked` events wired to our methods in the Code behind classes.

These two methods the only purpose (as of now) is to invoke the events and notify anyone that it's subscribed to them that an event happened.

Now in your `DashboardPage`

you will add this global property for simplicity

```
IMenuOptionHandler MenuOptionHandler => Content as IMenuOptionHandler;
```

This will cast the **Content** of the **Page**, whatever it's the value, to  `IMenuOptionHandler`. Any class that implements this interface will allow this cast to happen.

The last part to add on the same `DashboardPage` is the subscription to the events. These are gonna happen in the `OnAppearing` method and we will be unsubscribing on the `OnDisappearing`.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (MenuOptionHandler != null)
    {
        MenuOptionHandler.OnSlideIn += MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideIn;
        MenuOptionHandler.OnSlideOut += MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideOut;
    }
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    if (MenuOptionHandler != null)
    {
        MenuOptionHandler.OnSlideIn -= MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideIn;
        MenuOptionHandler.OnSlideOut -= MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideOut;
    }
}

void MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Logic to handle the SlideIn
    Debug.WriteLine("MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideIn");
}

void MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Logic to handle the SlideOut
    Debug.WriteLine("MenuOptionHandler_OnSlideOut");
}
```

Now, whenever one of the **Buttons** on the `ContentView` (iPhone or Tablet) is clicked, the Dashboard ContentPage will be notified about this and you will be able to perform any task you wish.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a button in Page1, first give a name to the Button in Xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btnInPage1" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />
```

In the code behind of Page1, create a `public static` property of button, and set the `btnPageOne = btnInPage1`:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{

    public static Button btnPageOne;
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        btnPageOne = btnInPage1;

    }
}
```

Then in your `DashboardPage`, you can access the button by using `Page1.btnPageOne`, and handle the logic with:

```
Page1.btnPageOne.Clicked += delegate {

    Console.WriteLine("Page1 btn clicked");

};
```

The same if you have Page2, Page3...